# Markdown editor in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm using ngx-markdown-editor in Angular 4. I want to use only the preview mode in ngx-markdown-editor.

```
<md-editor name="Content" [preRender]="preRenderFunc" [(ngModel)]="content" [height]="'200px'" [mode]="mode" [options]="options" required maxlength="500"></md-editor>
```

This will show with editor options. But I want only preview mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have build [this sample for you](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bz1q1q)

On your template you have to call component like this :

```
<md-editor name="Content" [ngModel]="content" mode="preview"></md-editor>
```

As you can see, Attribute without `[]` expect to have value as string / number but not variable. Above syntax have same effect than :

```
<md-editor name="Content" [ngModel]="content" [mode]="{{ preview }}"></md-editor>
```